# Averaging 1st column based on the number of duplicate rows (2nd/3rd columns)

Tags: bash, awk

I was wondering how the average of the 1st column can be calculated based on the number of duplicate rows in the 2nd/3rd columns (duplicate pairs of geographical coordinates). Example below:

```
170.0  -76.43  -13.963963964000001
170.0  -81.83  -5.07507507508
170.0  -79.67  -7.2972972973
130.0  -79.67  -7.2972972973
120.0  -79.67  -7.2972972973
100.0  -79.67  -7.2972972973
100.0  -79.67  -7.2972972973
100.0  -79.67  -7.2972972973
80.0   -79.67  -7.2972972973
70.0   -79.67  -7.2972972973
70.0   -79.67  -7.2972972973
50.0   -79.67  -7.2972972973
30.0   -79.67  -7.2972972973
300.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
260.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
230.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
170.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
160.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
140.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
130.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
120.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
110.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
100.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
100.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
100.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
100.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
100.0  -79.61  -8.07807807808
80.0   -79.61  -8.07807807808
80.0   -79.61  -8.07807807808
70.0   -79.61  -8.07807807808
70.0   -79.61  -8.07807807808
70.0   -79.61  -8.07807807808
60.0   -79.61  -8.07807807808
55.0   -79.61  -8.07807807808
50.0   -79.61  -8.07807807808
30.0   -79.61  -8.07807807808
300.0  -81.95  -5.13513513514
```

Using this `awk` call:

```
awk '{ array[$2]+=$3; count[$2]++ } END { for ( i in array ) print i, array[i]/count[i] }'
```

I get:

```
-76.43 -13.964
-79.61 -8.07808
-81.83 -5.07508
-81.95 -5.13514
-79.67 -7.2973
```

and the expected result is:

```
170.0  -76.43  -13.963963964000001
116.7  -79.61  -8.07807807808
170.0  -81.83  -5.07507507508
300.0  -81.95  -5.13513513514
92.7   -79.67  -7.2972972973
```

Any support is appreciated,

awk version: `GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)`

Comment: yeah I do! `GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)`

Comment: Then you can use multi-dimensional arrays! \o/ \o/ \o/ `awk '{++counter[$2][$3]; value[$2][$3] += $1} END {for (x in counter) for (y in counter[x]) print value[x][y] / counter[x][y], x, y}'`

Comment: neat!! great solution, many thanks @AndrejPodzimek! please I would like to mark it as the solution!

Comment: Glad it works. I’ve posted it as an answer with some formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `gawk` (the “default” `awk` on many Linux distros), one can use multi-dimensional arrays to accumulate the data, one for counters, one for sums of values:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

{
  ++counter[$2][$3]
  sum[$2][$3] += $1
}

END {
  for (x in counter)
    for (y in counter[x])
      print sum[x][y] / counter[x][y], x, y
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With any POSIX `awk` (output prefixed with `-|` ):

```
awk '{i=$2 " " $3; a[i]+=$1; n[i]+=1} END {for(i in a) print a[i]/n[i],i}' file
-| 300 -81.95 -5.13513513514
-| 116.739 -79.61 -8.07807807808
-| 170 -81.83 -5.07507507508
-| 92.7273 -79.67 -7.2972972973
-| 170 -76.43 -13.963963964000001
```

If you want only one digit after the decimal point and the alignment preserved:

```
awk '{i=$2 " " $3; a[i]+=$1; n[i]+=1}
  END {for(i in a) printf("%.1f %s\n", a[i]/n[i], i)}' file | column -t
-| 300.0  -81.95  -5.13513513514
-| 116.7  -79.61  -8.07807807808
-| 170.0  -81.83  -5.07507507508
-| 92.7   -79.67  -7.2972972973
-| 170.0  -76.43  -13.963963964000001
```

Answer (score 2):

In any awk:

```
awk '{a[$2,$3]+=$1; cnt[$2,$3]+=1} 
    END {
    for(e in a) {
        split(e,xy,SUBSEP)
        print a[e]/cnt[e], xy[1], xy[2]
    }
}' file
```

Prints:

```
92.7273 -79.67 -7.2972972973
116.739 -79.61 -8.07807807808
300 -81.95 -5.13513513514
170 -81.83 -5.07507507508
170 -76.43 -13.963963964000001
```

If you want to same decimals as your example output:

```
awk '{a[$2, $3] += $1; cnt[$2,$3] += 1} END {
    for(e in a) {
        split(e,xy,SUBSEP)
        printf "%.01f %.02f %.09f\n", a[e]/cnt[e], xy[1], xy[2]
    }
}' file | column -t
```

Prints:

```
92.7   -79.67  -7.297297297
116.7  -79.61  -8.078078078
300.0  -81.95  -5.135135135
170.0  -81.83  -5.075075075
170.0  -76.43  -13.963963964
```

If you want the output to be the same order as the pairs are encountered in the file, you best bet is with Ruby (which maintains insertion order of associative arrays / hashes):

```
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{x=Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []} }
lf=$F.map(&:to_f); x[lf[1..2]]<<lf[0]
END{x.each{|k,v| 
    printf("%.01f\t%.02f\t%.09f\n", "#{v.sum(0.0)/v.length}", k[0], k[1]) }}
' file
```

Prints:

```
170.0   -76.43  -13.963963964
170.0   -81.83  -5.075075075
92.7    -79.67  -7.297297297
116.7   -79.61  -8.078078078
300.0   -81.95  -5.135135135
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk and keeping almost nothing in memory in awk:

```
$ sort -nk2,3 file |
awk '
    { key = $2 OFS $3 }
    key != prev { prt(); tot=cnt=0; prev=key }
    { tot+=$1; cnt++ }
    END { prt() }
    function prt() { if (cnt) print tot/cnt, prev }
'
300 -81.95 -5.13513513514
170 -81.83 -5.07507507508
92.7273 -79.67 -7.2972972973
116.739 -79.61 -8.07807807808
170 -76.43 -13.963963964000001
```

If your file is guaranteed to be small enough to fit in memory and not make your script slow down significantly then you could instead do:

```
$ awk '
    {
        key = $2 OFS $3
        tot[key] += $1
        cnt[key] ++
    }
    END {
        for ( key in cnt ) {
            print tot[key]/cnt[key], key
        }
    }
' file
300 -81.95 -5.13513513514
116.739 -79.61 -8.07807807808
170 -81.83 -5.07507507508
92.7273 -79.67 -7.2972972973
170 -76.43 -13.963963964000001
```

Answer (score 1):

also check it out :

```
awk '
{
    sum[$2" "$3] += $1;
    count[$2" "$3]++;
}
END {
    for (key in sum) {
        print sum[key]/count[key], key;
    }
}' file.txt
```

and with perl

```
perl -lane '
    $sum{$F[1]." ".$F[2]} += $F[0];
    $count{$F[1]." ".$F[2]}++;
    END {
        foreach $key (keys %sum) {
            print $sum{$key}/$count{$key}, " ", $key
        }
    }
' file.txt
```